# Tag thead fixada no topo e tbody com barra de scroll em tabela no HTML

Tags: html, css

Quero uma tabela com a tag `thead` fixada no topo e `tbody` com um scroll na vertical, encontrei algumas soluções que utilizam apenas CSS, porém utilizam a propriedade `display`, removendo o comportamento padrão da tabela e tornando a mesma em `block`, impossibilitando de utilizar campos auto-ajustáveis, criando um desalinhamento com o título e os dados.

```css
dbgrid
{
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%; 
}
.dbgrid table
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.dbgrid thead
{
    background: #063b53;    
    color: #fff;
    width:100%;
}
.dbgrid tr
{   
    width:100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    
}
.dbgrid thead tr
{
    color:#fff;
    background:#000;
}
.dbgrid tbody tr
{
    color:#000;
    background:#FFF;
}
/** Testar barra de scroll com height:40px; **/
.dbgrid tbody
{
    width:100%;
    text-align: left;  
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height:40px;
    
  /** ao utilizar display:block funciona, porém perde algumas propriedades da tabela, como alinhar o título da coluna. 
  
  display:block;
  
  **/
    
}
```

```html
<div class="dbgrid">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Código</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Sobrenome</th>
                <th>Endereço</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>01</td>
                <td>João</td>
                <td>Silva</td>
                <td>Avenida Genérica N 12345</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>02</td>
                <td>Pedro</td>
                <td>Souza</td>
                <td>Rua Comum N 65478 - Bairro Qualquer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>03</td>
                <td>João</td>
                <td>Paulo</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>04</td>
                <td>Maria</td>
                <td>Carvalho</td>
                <td>Avenida Qualquer</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Essa é a tabela que eu tenho, remova o comentário do `display:block` e então o scroll irá funcionar, porém os campos irão desalinhar.

Há alguma solução? Aceito soluções que utilizem CSS puro ou Javascript, ou alguma combinação de ambos.

Grato.

Comment: Precisei fazer algo parecido, só que o scroll era horizontal, aí fiz com duas tabelas e divs que as englobavam para determinar o scroll.

Comment: Também tenho a possibilidade de utilizar uma div para englobar tudo, porém o problema é que o scroll é vertical, e gostaria que o título das colunas fosse mantido, neste caso se utilizasse a mesma solução que a sua, o título das colunas iria rolar junto ao scroll.

Comment: Você faz uma div para o título e outro para o tbody, aí o scroll você aplica somente na div do tbody, tipo esse [exemplo](http://copadomundo-se.com.br/time/128/roma), lá no final da página na aba cartões, é só você fazer ao contrário

Comment: Não é possível utilizar essa lógica na vertical, pois não pode-se utilizar divs na tabela que não estejam dentro do elemento td ou th, atuaria da mesma forma como definir o o tbody para block. Como eu havia ressaltado anteriormente, a solução é perfeita para utilizar na horizontal, porém na vertical não funciona.

Comment: Mas é para colocar div dentro da tabela não, seria uma para simular o thead e outra para o tbody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já existem algumas soluções pra isso Renan. Segue algumas interessantes:
***Utilizando em conjunto com JS:***

```js
        // Change the selector if needed
var $table = $('table.scroll'),
    $bodyCells = $table.find('tbody tr:first').children(),
    colWidth;

// Adjust the width of thead cells when window resizes
$(window).resize(function() {
    // Get the tbody columns width array
    colWidth = $bodyCells.map(function() {
        return $(this).width();
    }).get();
    
    // Set the width of thead columns
    $table.find('thead tr').children().each(function(i, v) {
        $(v).width(colWidth[i]);
    });    
}).resize(); // Trigger resize handler
```

```css
            table.scroll {
                width: 100%; /* Optional */
                /* border-collapse: collapse; */
                border-spacing: 0;
                border: 2px solid black;
            }

            table.scroll tbody,
            table.scroll thead { display: block; }

            thead tr th { 
                height: 30px;
                line-height: 30px;
                /*text-align: left;*/
            }

            table.scroll tbody {
                height: 100px;
                overflow-y: auto;
                overflow-x: hidden;
            }

            tbody { border-top: 2px solid black; }

            tbody td, thead th {
                width: 20%; /* Optional */
                border-right: 1px solid black;
            }

            tbody td:last-child, thead th:last-child {
                border-right: none;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="scroll">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Head 1</th>
            <th>Head 2</th>
            <th>Head 3</th>
            <th>Head 4</th>
            <th>Head 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Referência: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/CrSpu/554/

***Utilizando CSS puro:***

```css
.fixed {
  width:350px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.fixed th {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.fixed th,
.fixed td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  min-width: 200px;
}


.fixed thead {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fdfdfd;
}
.fixed thead tr {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.fixed tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table class="fixed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>phone</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>AAAA</td>
            <td>323232</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>BBBBB</td>
            <td>323232</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CCCCC</td>
            <td>3435656</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
            <td>AAAA</td>
            <td>323232</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>BBBBB</td>
            <td>323232</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CCCCC</td>
            <td>3435656</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Referência: http://jsbin.com/vujoyubu/1/edit?html,css,output

Basta adaptar pra sua necessidade agora.
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: A primeira solução é uma boa, já a segunda infelizmente utiliza largura fixa para as colunas, vou testar a primeira, obrigado Ricardo Moura.