# <thead> com topo fixo table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Eu tenho uma `<table>`, e gostaria de deixar o `<thead>` dela com topo fixo:

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover"
       id="tablepesquisaprodutos" style="font-size:12px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Código</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>Qtd</th>
            <th>Preço Un.</th>
            <th>Desc %</th>
            <th>Desc R$</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>ICMS</th>
            <th>Alíquota</th>
            <th>V.ICMS</th>
            <th>%ISS</th>
            <th>V.ISS</th>
            <th>%IPI</th>
            <th>V.IPI</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.PedidosProdutosF)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="link-check" onclick="PegaID(@item.Id);" onchange="cbChange(this);" /></td>
                <td>@item.CodigoProduto</td>
                <td>@item.Produto.nome</td>
                <td>@item.Qtd</td>
                <td>@item.PrecoUnitario.ToString("N2")</td>
                <td>@item.DescontoP.ToString("N2")</td>
                <td>@item.DescontoV.ToString("N2")</td>
                <td>@item.Total.ToString("N2")</td>
                <td>@item.ICMS</td>
                <td>@item.Aliquota.ToString("N2")</td>
                <td>@item.VICMS.ToString("N2")</td>
                <td>@item.ISS.ToString("N2")</td>
                <td>@item.VISS.ToString("N2")</td>
                <td>@item.IPI.ToString("N2")</td>
                <td>@item.VIPI.ToString("N2")</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Porém de toda forma que eu tento, ele cria uma *scroll* dentro da tabela, os campos ficam desalinhados, tem alguma configuração do `bootstrap` pra fazer isso, ou alguma outra forma que funcione?

Comment: Relacionada: [É possível adicionar um comportamento de overflow com scroll somente no tbody de uma table?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32304/5878)

Comment: Outra: [Fixar thead ao rolar a tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271288/5878)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss já tentei esta primeiro, porém ficam desalinhados, vou verificar os outros.

Comment: E busque fazer sempre um [mcve]. Postar o HTML com a estrutura do seu template não facilita muito. Tente gerar um HTML que possua os dados reais reproduzindo o problema que você citou. E, neste caso, você pode utilizar o snippet.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141185/tag-thead-fixada-no-topo-e-tbody-com-barra-de-scroll-em-tabela-no-html

Comment: Todas as formas que eu tento fazer de exemplo, o campo não fica responsive, ele fica fixo, e eu preciso que ele siga o padrão do bootstrap.

Comment: Mariana como o seu problema em questão era exclusivamente no Bootstrap eu preferir te responder aqui do que na nas outras respostas citadas aqui. Mas vou votar para fechar como duplicada ok, pois entendo ela como parte do escopo das outras perguntas tudo bem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cheguei em uma solução que funciona bem com o Bootstrap 3, testei aqui e não tive problema. Só tem um inconveniente... Não funciona no IE, pois utiliza o `position:sticky`, consulte aqui o suporte dos Browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky . *Tb precisei fazer um ajuste utilizando `box-shadow` para garantir que o texto que passa por traz do topo não vai aparecer*

Veja como ficou o resultado:

```css
.tabela {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.tabela th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #ddd, 0 -5px 0 0 #fff;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 tabela">
          <table class="table table-responsive table-hover"
          id="tablepesquisaprodutos" style="font-size:12px;">
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th></th>
               <th>Código</th>
               <th>Descrição</th>
               <th>Qtd</th>
               <th>Preço Un.</th>
               <th>Desc %</th>
               <th>Desc R$</th>
               <th>Total</th>
               <th>ICMS</th>
               <th>Alíquota</th>
               <th>V.ICMS</th>
               <th>%ISS</th>
               <th>V.ISS</th>
               <th>%IPI</th>
               <th>V.IPI</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <!-- @foreach (var item in Model.PedidosProdutosF)
           { -->
               <tr>
                   <td><input type="checkbox" class="link-check" onclick="PegaID(@item.Id);" onchange="cbChange(this);" /></td>
                   <td>@item.CodigoProduto</td>
                   <td>@item.Produto.nome</td>
                   <td>@item.Qtd</td>
                   <td>@item.PrecoUnitario.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.DescontoP.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.DescontoV.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.Total.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.ICMS</td>
                   <td>@item.Aliquota.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.VICMS.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.ISS.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.VISS.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.IPI.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.VIPI.ToString("N2")</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td><input type="checkbox" class="link-check" onclick="PegaID(@item.Id);" onchange="cbChange(this);" /></td>
                   <td>@item.CodigoProduto</td>
                   <td>@item.Produto.nome</td>
                   <td>@item.Qtd</td>
                   <td>@item.PrecoUnitario.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.DescontoP.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.DescontoV.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.Total.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.ICMS</td>
                   <td>@item.Aliquota.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.VICMS.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.ISS.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.VISS.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.IPI.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.VIPI.ToString("N2")</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td><input type="checkbox" class="link-check" onclick="PegaID(@item.Id);" onchange="cbChange(this);" /></td>
                   <td>@item.CodigoProduto</td>
                   <td>@item.Produto.nome</td>
                   <td>@item.Qtd</td>
                   <td>@item.PrecoUnitario.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.DescontoP.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.DescontoV.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.Total.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.ICMS</td>
                   <td>@item.Aliquota.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.VICMS.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.ISS.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.VISS.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.IPI.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.VIPI.ToString("N2")</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td><input type="checkbox" class="link-check" onclick="PegaID(@item.Id);" onchange="cbChange(this);" /></td>
                   <td>@item.CodigoProduto</td>
                   <td>@item.Produto.nome</td>
                   <td>@item.Qtd</td>
                   <td>@item.PrecoUnitario.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.DescontoP.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.DescontoV.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.Total.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.ICMS</td>
                   <td>@item.Aliquota.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.VICMS.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.ISS.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.VISS.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.IPI.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.VIPI.ToString("N2")</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td><input type="checkbox" class="link-check" onclick="PegaID(@item.Id);" onchange="cbChange(this);" /></td>
                   <td>@item.CodigoProduto</td>
                   <td>@item.Produto.nome</td>
                   <td>@item.Qtd</td>
                   <td>@item.PrecoUnitario.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.DescontoP.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.DescontoV.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.Total.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.ICMS</td>
                   <td>@item.Aliquota.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.VICMS.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.ISS.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.VISS.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.IPI.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.VIPI.ToString("N2")</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td><input type="checkbox" class="link-check" onclick="PegaID(@item.Id);" onchange="cbChange(this);" /></td>
                   <td>@item.CodigoProduto</td>
                   <td>@item.Produto.nome</td>
                   <td>@item.Qtd</td>
                   <td>@item.PrecoUnitario.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.DescontoP.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.DescontoV.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.Total.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.ICMS</td>
                   <td>@item.Aliquota.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.VICMS.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.ISS.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.VISS.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.IPI.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.VIPI.ToString("N2")</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td><input type="checkbox" class="link-check" onclick="PegaID(@item.Id);" onchange="cbChange(this);" /></td>
                   <td>@item.CodigoProduto</td>
                   <td>@item.Produto.nome</td>
                   <td>@item.Qtd</td>
                   <td>@item.PrecoUnitario.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.DescontoP.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.DescontoV.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.Total.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.ICMS</td>
                   <td>@item.Aliquota.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.VICMS.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.ISS.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.VISS.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.IPI.ToString("N2")</td>
                   <td>@item.VIPI.ToString("N2")</td>
               </tr>
           <!-- } -->
       </tbody>
      </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo, toda forma que eu tentava, ficava desproporcional, por ser responsive. Muito útil.

Comment: @marianac_costa massa! Essa opção vai funcionar em 95% dos navegadores, só não vai ficar fixo no IE infelizmente.